# Lunetics locale flags

Tags: symfony, twig, locale

Is it possible to show flags (images, icons) in lunetics/locale-bundle? By default is unordered list with text like:

```
<ul class="locale_chooser">
    {% for locale in locales %}
        <li{% if current_locale == locale.locale %} class="locale_current"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{{ locale.link }}" title="{{ locale.locale_current_language }}">{{ locale.locale_current_language }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: where are you looking to show them? inline with the A tag?

Comment: Yes. I want to show inside <a></a> tag. There is solution with if sentences where I for example check if locale is en then show en flag etc.  But this is not permanent solution, because I will have to add another if sentence when add new locale.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Icons from css sprite:

```
<ul class="language-switcher">
    {% for locale in locales %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ locale.link }}" class="icon language-{{ locale.locale }}" title="{{ locale.locale_current_language }}"> </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

CSS code example:

```
.icon {
  background-image: url('../images/sprite.png'); }

.language-switcher .language-en {
  background-position: -5px -7817px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px; }
```

HTML code example with icons as files:

```
<ul class="language-switcher">
    {% for locale in locales %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ locale.link }}" title="{{ locale.locale_current_language }}"><img src="\images\{{ locale.locale }}.png" /></a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```